# java version error for loading xlsx package in R

Tags: r, xlsx

I have a lot of R scripts where xlsx package is used. When I use `library(xlsx)` to load it, I got java version errors like this:

`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'xlsx', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: Your java version is 12.  Need 1.5.0 or higher.
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘xlsx’ was built under R version 3.5.2`

I used `sudo R CMD javareconf` to reset java versions to the right one, but still could not load xlsx correctly in Studio or R console. **Oddly enough**, when I run the same R scripts in Mac terminal command line, like, `Rscript foo.R`, I can successfully load the library without errors. Somebody can help me to re-configure the Java in R console or Rstudio?

I am using MacOs Majave. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One way to skirt around the issue would be to use the tidyverse's [readxl package](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/), which doesn't require Java.